# Apache Reverse Proxy on Sharepoint server how to Preserve Proxy Port

Tags: apache, sharepoint, reverse-proxy

I am adding apache reverse proxy for the sharepoint server.
Below is the virtual host config.

```
< VirtualHost *:80 >

    ServerName spdev1.domain.com 
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader unset Origin
    #ProxyVia Off


    <Proxy *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://172.16.2.1:8001/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.16.2.1:8001/
< /VirtualHost>
```

When I access the URL http://spdev1.domain.com, the Sharepoint site is getting redirected to http://spdev1.domain.com:8001.

How do I preserve the Proxy Port number, 80, in the response instead of redirecting to port 8001?

Is any change needed in the Sharepoint site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the Alternate Access Mapping from Internal URL to Public URL.